# mange is delete(soft delete) in mongodb by passing it in filter checking the existing criteria

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a situation where I have to check name of the company and code of the company and if both match with existing than it should say exists, or if one of them is matched in existing db then also it should be saying it exists.
How would I use in mongo?
So if the data receive isDeleted true than I also want to add in if section that checks if not adding than goes for checking id and update, than I also want to pass isDelete, so that if any data received which is previously deleted so that it can set to false again.
how would I handle this delete scenario?

```
{
    "userId":"tt838984984s",
  "company":{
  "addressee" : {
      "addressee" : "Ms.1", 
      "title_name" : "", 
      "salutation" : "Drks:", 
      "comments" : "", 
      "email" : "opus7ent@example.com", 
      "phone" : "123456666", 
      "fax" : "", 
      "extention_group" : "", 
      "ext" : ""
  }, 
  "abbreviation" : "", 
  "care_of" : "", 
  "address_1" : "HELLO2",
  "address_2" : "", 
  "address_3" : "", 
  "state" : "CA", 
  "zip" : "90024", 
  "is_deleted" : true, 
  "company_code" : "ABACAB", 
  "parent_company" : null, 
  "name" : "Abacab", 
  "createdBy" : "Data lolz", 
  "modifiedBy" : "Data", 
  "createdDate" : "2019-08-22T19:10:50.000+0000", 
  "modifiedDate" : "2019-08-22T19:10:50.000+0000", 
  "company_id_legacy" :1246, 
  "__v" : 0, 
  "is_registered_for" : false,

},
}


  is_deleted == false
    if(!isAdd) {
          filter["_id"] ={ "$ne" : id};
           }
        let filter = {
                 name: { $regex: new RegExp(`^${company.name}$`, 'i') },
                 company_code: { $regex: new RegExp(`^${company.company_code}$`, 'i') }
    }
    cModel.find(filter, function (err, docs) {
                            if (docs.length) {
                                result.error = "Name already exists: " + company.name;
                                console.log("Name already exists", null);
                                let resp = api_respose.getSuccessResponse(process.env.WEB_URI, result.error);
                                resolve(resp);
                            }
    else{
     ///saving here
    }
```

Now suppose I pass that JSON, and if there's `is_deleted = false` (this is Json while adding new entry in db)
And now if there's some old entry with `name` or `company_code` exists in db with `is_delete =true` then it throws error that *name already exits*

Now my question is how to resolve this scenario? Like I want to overwrite that file with new entry or is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: what's your actual requirement, so your `OR` will give what you're expecting checking for name or code exists. Your requirement apart from this is not clear

Comment: So if the data receive isDeleted == true then I also want to add in if section that checks if not adding than goes for checking id and update.

Then I also want to pass isDelete, so that if any data received which is previously deleted so that it can set to false again.

How would I handle this delete scenario?

Comment: @Subburaj please check the question again

Comment: What is `isAdd`???

Comment: First thing What exactly is your requirement is not at all clear by your question.
What i understand is you have some entity where company name and company code are the unique fields, and then you have one field called isDeleted which will be set whenever you delete the entity. Now what do you want to do?
1. do you want to add a new entity with the same comapany name and company code ?
2. do you want to just restore deleted entity -- that means just resetting the isDeleted to false again?

Comment: `let isAdd = false;` isAdd is if there no `id` passed than it set to true and create new entry in db.@Subburaj

Comment: @Lucia yes, I want something like that to reset in the same entry

Comment: @Farhan As you said if id is not passed means then it should create entry in DB right?? If this is the case the you can straightly save it, then y r u checking for filter condition over there??

Comment: @Subburaj is right. But i think he has "ID" as a seperate field, and company name and company code are also unique in his entity, is it right @Farhan?
In that case why dont you make company_code as primary key?
Or if you want to use your existing approach you can use findAndUpdate which will update isDeleted to true if there is document with you find criteria else you can just save the entity as new into DB.
 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate